# Why is RedirectToAction and Index method in same area searching for view in root?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am having problems with using `RedirectToAction("Index")` in a controller within an `Admin` area.

When the Redirect occurs, it hits a breakpoint within the Index method on the controller so I know the redirect is working.  However, it fails to find the view.

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? Id)
    {
        var model = _leadOriginService.GetEditorModel(Id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

The exception shows a list of the views it is trying to resolve in the root and not in the area.  It seems that it has lost the context of the area it is in.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Any chance that your `GetEditorModel` method returns a string? In which folders is it exactly looking for a view file?

Comment: Type of model shouldn't matter as the return View(model) works on other actions fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call RedirectToAction in another fashion as MVC might not be possible to infer the Area from the way you are calling it, so you need to specify it..

Try

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "yourController", new {Area="Admin"})
```

Or

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new {Area="Admin"})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that Major byte. Your 2nd answer works as I had found out from my own investigation. It still doesn't explain why other action methods don't need to specify the area parameter, seems a little inconsistent if sometimes I have to specify the area in my action methods.

Comment: Might depend on the fact that if these actions  **only** exist in a specific area controller, while for *Index* it. Will hit your default route first (as no controller is specified)? Hard to answer without knowing where it tries to look for the views...